# If a computer can demonstrate singleton sets are closed, is the space Hausdorff?

Tags: computability, semi-decidability, topology

In Haskell, I made a class of admissible (that is, second-countable and $T_0$) spaces:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Admissible a where
    type BasisElem a -- Type of a basis element
    semidecide :: a -> BasisElem a -> [Bool] -- Semidecides whether an element is in a basis element
    countFirst :: a -> [BasisElem a] -- Computes a countable basis at an element
    countSecond :: a -> [BasisElem a] -- Computes a countable basis (the parameter is dummy)
    countDense :: [a] -- Computes a countable dense subset
```

`semidecide` outputs a list having a `True` if and only if the element is in the basis element. Generally, it is not a decider; the output may be an infinite list of `False`s.

I tried to make a class of Fréchet ($T_1$) spaces and a class of Hausdorff ($T_2$) spaces. The sketch was:

```
class Admissible a => Frechet a where
    frechet :: a -> [BasisElem a]

class Frechet a => Hausdorff a where
    hausdorff :: a -> a -> [Bool]
```

`frechet` outputs the open set whose complement is the singleton set of given element.

`hausdorff` semidecides the inequality $≠$.

But apparently, if `frechet` is present, `hausdorff` is redundant? Like this:

```
weaveOmegaSq :: [[a]] -> [a]
weaveOmegaSq = go 1
  where
    go n xss = let
        partitioned = do
            (us, vs) <- fmap (splitAt n) xss
            [us, vs]
        in case partitioned of
            [] -> []
            xs:yss -> xs ++ go (1 + n) (go2 yss)
    go2 [] = []
    go2 [xs] = [xs]
    go2 (xs:ys:xss) = (ys ++ xs) : go2 xss

hausdorff x y = weaveOmegaSq (fmap (semidecide x) (frechet y))
```

`weaveOmegaSq` is a bijection from the ordinal $\omega^2$ to $\omega$.

Does this mean, if a computer can demonstrate singleton sets are closed, the space is Hausdorff? What's the rigorous proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, having your map frechet available and having your map hausdorff available is equivalent. You can find this in my article [Topological aspects of the theory of represented spaces](https://content.iospress.com/articles/computability/com049) ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.3763)). The proof is a very straight-forward currying/uncurrying affair.

If you are only working with second-countable spaces, this is essentially the end of the story. But beyond them, it gets a bit tricky because there the semidecidability of inequality no longer implies the topological characterization of Hausdorffness, namely that there are disjoint open sets separating the points. Matthias Schröder has found a few examples, eg the one-point compactification of the Baire space has semidecidable inequality, but the point at infinity is not separated from the others by any pair of disjoint open sets.